# Resolve a code review by default on check in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have code, code reviews, and work items (all of which are visible under Visual Studio's Team Explorer > Pending changes if they are related to the current code). Parent TFS work items by default are set to `Associate`, Child work items by default are set to `Resolve` (marking them done on check-in), and Visual Studio code reviews by default are set to `Associate`. But I have noticed that if I manually change the Code Review to `Resolve`, then check-in, it will complete the code review for me. How do I make `Resolve` the default action for Code Reviews?

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been added to Visual Studio 2015 to allow users to choose whether or not the “Resolve” action is the default.

The setting is under Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server:

[image]

Comment: So I have that checked, yet Code Reviews are still `Associate` by default

Comment: Yes, the code review is still 'Associate'' in pending changes. But with this item selected, once you perform a check-in, the code review will have a “Resolve” action.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work Cece, if the code review work item says "Associate" when the "Check In" button is pressed, the code review does not get completed. However if "Resolve" is selected then it does.

Comment: This only applies to **task** work item's, not **review** work item's unfortunately. I'm in search for the same. :(

Comment: @derekantrican  In my opinion, make Resolve the default action isn't make sense, the code review should be completed by reviewer instead of the default action when check in changes. There is the risk if user check in changes before code review be completed, so I think the Associate default action is make sense.